# Does NASware useful when used only on one of two disk of a NAS?

Tags: nas

I have a WD My Cloud EX2, with one WD Red drive, and one cheap drive, in a RAID 0. I want to know if NASware is usefull with this configuration, or I need to have two red drives to make use of all NASware advantages.

I mean, do this configuration activates NASware, or the fact that one of the drives is not a drive with NASware can desactivate it?